# Mongoose/mongoDB: Limit returned documents around singular documents position

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following mongoose query that returns all videos by the same uploader to create a list of videos that will appear on the right side of the currently playing video. The query works and returns the videos, but if a uploader has a lot of videos (some uploaders have over 3,000) too much data gets sent to the frontend and all the video thumbnails loading in makes the page very slow. To fix this I want to limit the amount of videos that can be returned like this to 100.

```js
const uploaderVideos = await Video.find(
    { uploader: currentVideo.uploader })
    .sort({ uploadDate: -1 })
    .lean()
    .exec();
```

Typically you would just add `.limit(100)` to the above code to limit the amount of videos returned. However, I want the videos returned to reflect the position of the currently playing video. For example:

If the video is the first video uploaded by a uploader with more than 100 videos

```
* The video
- The 99 next videos
```

If the video is the 200th video uploaded by a uploader with 1,300 videos

```
- Videos 150-199
* The video (video 200)
- Videos 201-250
```

If the video is the 70th video uploaded by a uploader with 100 videos

```
- Videos 1-69
* The video (video 70)
- Videos 71-100
```

If the video is the last video uploaded by a uploader with 300 videos

```
- Videos 200-299
* The video (video 300)
```

How would I accomplish this with a mongoose query?

Comment: Do you know the index of the item when it is being requested. I.e. do you know if its the 70th video they are requesting, or is it just by an id?

Either way, I think you'll have to write some custom logic using skip/limit and count, there isn't a native mongo/mongoose way to solve this AFAIK.